# how do I remove question mark(?) from a data set in R

Tags: r, na

Hello everyone I am analysing UCI adult `census` data. The data has question marks (`?`) for every missing value.

I want to replace all the question marks with `NA`.

i tried:

```
library(XML)
census<-read.csv("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.data",header=F,na.strings="?")
names(census)<-c("Age","Workclass","Fnlwght","Education","EducationNum","MaritalStatus","Occupation"   
  ,"Relationship" , "Race","Gender","CapitalGain","CapitalLoss","HoursPerWeek","NativeCountry","Salary"  )

table(census$Workclass)

                ?       Federal-gov         Local-gov      Never-worked           Private      Self-emp-inc 
             1836               960              2093                 7             22696              1116 
 Self-emp-not-inc         State-gov       Without-pay 
             2541              1298                14 

x

<-ifelse(census$Workclass=="?",NA,census$Workclass)
 table(x)
x
    1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9 
 1836   960  2093     7 22696  1116  2541  1298    14
```

but it did not work.

Please help.

Comment: It's probably better if you read the dataset in with `na.strings = "?"` in the first place. Otherwise, I recommend [`makemeNA` from my SOfun package](https://github.com/mrdwab/SOfun/blob/master/R/makemeNA.R).

Comment: This code should work - `x <- c(1,2,"?",3); ifelse(x=="?",NA,x)` - does for me anyway.

Comment: What @thela?!? You're the `replace` spokesperson, not `ifelse`! `replace(x, x == "?", NA)`.

Comment: @AnandaMahto - I hang my head in shame. I was just too keen to point out that OP's code should work already.

Comment: It looks like you should use `na.strings = " ?"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

look at gsub

```
census$x <- gsub("?",NA,census$x, fixed = TRUE)
```

edit: forgot to add `fixed = TRUE`

As Richard pointed out, this will catch all occurrences of a ?

Comment: Is this just a guess? I don't think it would work like this (without at least `fixed = TRUE` or escaping the "?").

Comment: gsub() function is not returning a data frame

Comment: @Learner27, why would it when he's just using it on one of the variables? Please update your question with a *small* reproducible example and the answers might improve.

Comment: This will catch every occurrence of a question mark, possibly more than just the desired  NA values A `^?$` regex would be safer

Answer (score 9):

Here's an easy way to replace `" ?"` with `NA` in all columns.

```
# find elements
idx <- census == " ?"
# replace elements with NA
is.na(census) <- idx
```

*How it works?*

The command `idx <- census == " ?"` creates a logical matrix with the same numbers of rows and columns as the data frame `census`. This matrix `idx` contains `TRUE` where `census` contains `" ?"` and `FALSE` at the other positions.

The matrix `idx` is used as an index. The command `is.na(census) <- idx` is used to replace values in `census` at the positions in `idx` with `NA`.

Note that the function `is.na<-` is used here. It is not identical with the `is.na` function.

Comment: Can you explain why this works? =/ first I thought the code was wrong, then i tried it.. and it works. and I have no idea why.

Comment: @zelite I added an explanation.

Comment: Thanks. I was confused in the 'is.na<-' part. now I just have to go check what's the difference between this and the 'is.na'. :)

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, when I import this dataset into R, the question marks are read in as integers.

Here's what I did to code all of the question marks to N/A's. I'm sure there are better ways of doing this but my R skills aren't the greatest and this worked for me.

**col_names:**

```
names <- list(
    'age','workclass','fnlwgt',
    'education','education-num',
    'marital-status','occupation',
    'relationship','race','sex',
    'capital-gain','capital-loss',
    'hours-per-week','native-country', 'salary'
)
```

**Code:**

```
# Save csv as variable adult
adult <- read.csv("~/.../adult.data", col.names = names)

for(i in 1:length(adult)) {
    matches <- grepl("\\?", adult[ ,i])
    for(j in 1:length(matches)) {
        ifelse(matches[j] == TRUE, adult[j,i] <- "NA", matches[j])
    }
}
```